# How can I evaluate the left limit of this function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits-without-lhopital

If $f(x) = {{\sqrt[4]{x^2\tan^2 4x}}\over{2x}}$

How can I evaluate 
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x)$$

Here's what I tried:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0^-} {{\sqrt[4]{x^2\tan^2 4x}}\over{2x}}
& = {1\over 2}\lim_{x\to 0^-} {{\sqrt[4]{x^2\tan^2 4x}}\over{x}} \\ 
& = {1\over 2}\lim_{x\to 0^-} {{\sqrt[4]{x^2\tan^2 4x}}\over{-\sqrt[4]{x^4}}} \\
& = -{1\over 2}\lim_{x\to 0^-} \sqrt[4]{{x^2\tan^2 4x}\over{x^4}}
\end{align}

In the second step I wrote $x$ as $-\sqrt[4]{x^4}$ because we are working with the left limit which is on the left of $0$

\begin{align}
-{1\over 2}\lim_{x\to 0^-} \sqrt[4]{{x^2\tan^2 4x}\over{x^4}} & = -{1\over 2}\lim_{x\to 0^-} \sqrt[4]{{\tan^2 4x}\over{x^2}} \\
& = -{1\over 2}\lim_{x\to 0^-} \sqrt[4]{\left({\tan 4x}\over{x}\right)^2} \\
& = -{1\over 2} \sqrt[4]{\left( \lim_{x\to 0^-} {{\tan 4x}\over{x}}\right)^2} \\
& = -{1\over 2} \sqrt[4]{(4)^2} \\
& = -{1\over 2} \sqrt[4]{16} \\
& = -{1\over 2}  × 2 = -1
\end{align}

Are all these steps correct?
I feel something wrong about the second step, because I found some other people who solved it $1$ and not $-1$ as my solution brought me.

Comment: No I haven't but if you look at the tags, you will see that I don't want to use l'Hopital

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: In that case, you'll probably need to split up tan into sin/cos, and use the usual identities for $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin(x)/x=1$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}(1-\cos(x))/x=0$.

Comment: Take the $2x$ inside the root and cancel the $x^2$. Denominator will become $16x^2$. Then use $\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{tan(x)}{x}}=1$

Comment: Only that with sine @Ben.

Answer (score 1):

I would write $$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\sqrt{|x\tan(4x)|}}{2x}$$